# A JAVA Program wants call Mathematica's Reduce function to solve equation and get the result

Tags: equation-solving, java

```java
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.setProperty("com.wolfram.jlink.libdir", "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\SystemFiles\\Links\\JLink");
    KernelLink ml = null;
    try {
        ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink("-linkmode launch -linkname "
                + "'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\MathKernel.exe'");
        // empty the compute enviroment
        ml.discardAnswer();
    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ml.evaluate("Reduce[ 2k < 10 && k > 2 , k ]");
        ml.waitForAnswer();
        String s = ml.getString();
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Error:
    MathLinkException: 3: MLGet out of sequence.
    at com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.getString
    at com.wolfram.jlink.WrappedKernelLink.getString
    at mathematica_lym.Test.main

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your Reduce returns a result of type Inequality. But then you're trying to read it as String. That's the wrong type to use, Java doesn't know what a type of Inequality is. You can verify this by replacing the Reduce expression by something that returns a string, or by appending a semicolon and then return a string, because that's what you want to read it in as.

```java
ml.evaluate("Reduce[ 2k < 10 && k > 2 , k ];ToString[12345]");
```

You probably want something like

```java
ml.evaluate("Reduce[ 2k < 10 && k > 2 , k ]//ToString");
```

Keep in mind that MathLink (from which the KernelLink inherits) is a packet-based system. So when you get a "MLGet out of sequence" error, you can be quite sure that in the packet pingpong something was sent that was not of the right type that was expected by the receiver.

Comment: I can get the mathematica's result through your method.Can i only get the Integers from the Function Reduce[2k < 10 && k > 2,k,Integers]?

Comment: same thing: ml.evaluate("Reduce[2k < 10 && k > 2,k,Integers]//ToString");